# Execute Stored Procedure using Trigger on VIEW when multiple columns are updated with specific values

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, view, triggers

I have a **VIEW** (in SQL SERVER) containing the following  columns:

```
itemID[vachar(50)]|itemStatus [vachar(20)]|itemCode[vachar(20)]|itemTime[varchar(5)]
```

The itemID column contains id values that do not change. The remaining 3 rows however get updated periodically. I understand it is more difficult create a trigger on a VIEW.

An example of the table containing data would be:

```
 |itemID|imtemStatus|itemCode|itemTime|
 |------|-----------|--------|--------|
 |  1   |  OK       |  30    |  00:10 |
 |------|-----------|--------|--------|
 |  2   |  OK       |  40    |  02:30 |
 |------|-----------|--------|--------|
 |  3   |  STOPPED  |  30    |  00:01 |
 |------|-----------|--------|--------|
```

When itemStatus = STOPPED **&** itemCode = 30

I would like to execute a stored procedure (sp_Alert) passing the itemID as a parameter

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You can't put a trigger on a view, and it's not the way to do what you want anyway.   Instead of asking about views and stored procedures, explain what you're actually trying to achieve.   The way you want to do it is almost certainly not the best way.

Comment: @TabAlleman cant views have `instead of` triggers ?

Comment: The trigger you are referencing would belong on the base table. But I have to agree that something seems less than ideal in the concept here. The biggest issue with your question is that is not clear what you are really trying to do here.

Comment: Hmm, I stand corrected.  You can put triggers on updateable views.   Still sounds like a bad idea in this case.   https://michaeljswart.com/2012/10/triggers-on-views-what-for/

Comment: @Tab Alleman you can put triggers on views. I&#39;m trying to execute a stored procedure when the two values mentioned in the question are present. Would you have any suggestions on how to achieve this? *edit* without a trigger

Answer (score 1):

Since a trigger is at least "not easy", I'd like to propose an ugly but functional way out. You can create a stored procedure that checks ItemCode and ItemStatus. If they match your criteria you can start the sp_Alert from this procedure.

```
create procedure check_status as 
if (select 1 
      from vw_itemstatus 
     where itemStatus = 'STOPPED' 
       and itemCode = 30) is not null
begin
declare @item_id int 
    set @item_id = (select itemID 
                      from vw_itemstatus 
                     where itemStatus = 'STOPPED' 
                       and itemCode = 30)
    exec sp_Alert @item_id
end
```

Depending on how critical this functionality is and how many resources you can use for it, you can schedule this procedure via the SQL Server Agent. If you run this with a short interval, it will work "similar" to what you had in mind.

Comment: cheers for your suggestion. I could execute this using PHP, JavaScript with server sent events, I am however trying to develop a SQL only solution (networking issues, browser issues etc!), I was also looking at Task Scheduler, however the minimum 'execution' time is 1 minute and I'm trying to track realtime data changes. I'll investigate SQL Server Agent further.